# check if a line is empty using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do a simple comparison to check if a line is empty using bash:

```
line=$(cat test.txt | grep mum )
if [ "$line" -eq "" ]
        then
        echo "mum is not there"
    fi
```

But it is not working, it says:  [: too many arguments

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could also use the `$?` variable that is set to the return status of the command.  So you'd have:

```
line=$(grep mum test.txt)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo "mum is not there"
fi
```

For the `grep` command if there are any matches `$?` is set to 0 (exited cleanly) and if there are no matches `$?` is 1.

Comment: You can also just do `if grep -q mum test.txt; then ...`

Comment: In this specific scenario this work, indeed. However, try adding a couple of pipes and see how well this technique works.

Comment: @Anders, that technique works perfectly well, assuming you want to test the exit status of the last command in the pipeline.

Answer (score 8):

```
if [ ${line:-null} = null ]; then
    echo "line is empty"
fi
```

or

```
if [ -z "${line}" ]; then
    echo "line is empty"
fi
```

Comment: @schot, Yes, you're correct, which is why I included the second one also. Pick an arbitrary choice of a data input that you know won't occur. Otherwise just select the second option. Pike and Kernighan prefers the first option in "The UNIX Programming Environment".

Comment: The second one should either quote the variable or use `[[` (You should always use `[[` when using bash). In the case of `-z` it works, but for any other test, it will cause an error if the variable is empty.

Comment: Daenyth: if unquoted, it not necessary works correctly even with -z. Try `line="foo -o bar"; if [ -z $line ]; then echo "line is empty"; else echo "line is not empty"; fi`

Answer (score 5):

The classical sh answer that will also work in bash is

```
if [ x"$line" = x ]
then
    echo "empty"
fi
```

Your problem could also be that you are using '-eq' which is for arithmetic comparison.

Comment: This is the classical for ancient, obsolete and broken shells! Please don't use this in new code.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep "mum" file || echo "empty"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if line=$(grep -s -m 1 -e mum file.txt)
then
    echo "Found line $line"
else
    echo 'Nothing found or error occurred'
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the clearest solution is using regex:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ ^$ ]]; then
    echo "line empty"
else
    echo "line not empty"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use `PHP` with this,

```
$path_to_file='path/to/your/file';
$line = trim(shell_exec("grep 'mum' $path_to_file |wc -l"));
if($line==1){
   echo 'mum is not here';
}
else{
   echo 'mum is here';
}
```

Comment: why would anybody ever want to do that? Additionally the OP explicitly requested a bash answer..